Apache Ignite - Can I share the igniteCache object across webapps in single tomcat instance
Can I share the igniteCache object between webapps by setting custom class loaders in tomcat instance?
Note: I can not start single ignite instance at tomcat instance. I have ignite server running in one webapp, and client node in another web app. But these two webapps access POJO objects through class loaders.
I am experiencing below issue.
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerInaccessibleClassException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading) [clsLdr=ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: archive
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@6576fe71
, cls=com.xxx..UserContextBaseElement]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:257) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:225) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:92) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1846) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:2071) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1889) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1880) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1871) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.unmarshal(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:271) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.unmarshal(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:1254) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectAdapter.valueFromValueBytes(CacheObjectAdapter.java:75) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectImpl.value(CacheObjectImpl.java:92) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:199) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:78) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:138) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheEventManager.addEvent(GridCacheEventManager.java:323) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheEventManager.addEvent(GridCacheEventManager.java:190) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheEventManager.addEvent(GridCacheEventManager.java:126) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerGet0(GridCacheMapEntry.java:736) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerGet(GridCacheMapEntry.java:579) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.localGet(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:522) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.tryLocalGet(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:434) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.mapKeyToNode(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:401) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.map(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:278) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.init(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:242) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.getAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1423) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$1200(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:147) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$12.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:467) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$12.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:465) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.asyncOp(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:752) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.getAsync(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:465) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:4682) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.repairableGet(GridCacheAdapter.java:4648) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:1331) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.get(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1107) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.UserContextBaseElement
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.88]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.88]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]

